# Scraping - Problem locating Web Elements from Webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a Webpage where some IDs need to be sought for. I am using Python with the Selenium Driver.

In order to access the search screen, I try to locate the "search" button and click on it. I have tried many methods to do this but I always get an exception in Python. I used to invoke these links with VBA IE scraping and it was really easy.

When inspecting the HTML on Chrome, the element is as follows:

```
"a target="content" href="search/search/BaseFormular.start" 
id="Search.Customer" onmouseover="nav_enter('NewSearch.Customer','by 
Customer'); return true;" onclick="nav_enter('NewSearch.Customer','by 
Customer'); return true;" onmouseout="nav_leave('NewSearch.Customer',''); 
return true;">by Customer /a>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I could possibly click on this element in Python with Selenium? Is there any way to write all `WebElements` on a page to a file in order to learn how to select them individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by xpath like so:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_from_webpage').click()
```

to find the XPath you can (in chrome) right-click on the element, at the bottom of the list inspect:

[image: open google chrome inspect element]

your element should be highlighted, right-click then copy -> copy as XPath (or full XPath)

[image: google chrome inspect element copy as]

replace xpath_from_webpage in the code snippet above with the XPath you have just copied